# What should I use for zipping instead of GZipStream in Windows Mobile?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, zip, gzipstream

I am developing an application for Windows Mobile 6 in Microsoft Visual Studio 2005. I have to unzip a text received by web service. But when I use GZipStream I get the following error:

> Error  1   The type or namespace name 'GZipStream' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What should I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.

The <strike>brand new</strike> [Compact Framework 3.5 Beta1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=1343d537-a62f-4a6e-9727-7791bf4cc2bd&DisplayLang=en) now contains Compression!

Introduction

The Compact Framework is missing a crucial namespace for mobile device development - System.IO.Compression. In here lies the ability to compress text, xml, files or any Stream using popular ZIP compression. You can use it to save storage space on the device by compressing data used by your application. Or you can use it to compress information before transmitting it to a server to save GPRS costs and speed up transfer times. Simply use this library in the exact same way you would on the full framework.

Download Links

[Free Download For CF1](http://www.aspecto-software.com/ccount/click.php?id=10)

[Free Download For CF2](http://www.aspecto-software.com/ccount/click.php?id=9)

---

[My reference](http://www.aspecto-software.com/rw/applications/developer/compression/index.html)

Comment: May of '07 is hardly "brand new", and why install a beta, when you can install the release that came out after it? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=65

Answer (score 1):

GZipStream support was added to the Compact Framework in version 3.5. To develop for the CF 3.5 you need Visual Studio 2008 (VS 2010 does **not** support development for the Compact Framework).

If your locked into Visual Studio 2005 and you have no control over the web service you consume you can create a intermediary web service to basically repackage the data into a format supported by CF 2.0.